# How to implement command autocomplete in myshell?

Tags: shell, readline

I am making my own shell in C. I know one can use the `readline` library to make use of autocompletion of paths using TAB, but it can only be used for autocompletion of paths but not commands.

For example, if I write *clea* and press the TAB key, it does not make it *clear*, nor does it give suggestions for any similar commands on pressing TAB twice. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your shell also needs to implement a `PATH` variable, which is a list of directories to search for non-builtin commands. For instance, if `PATH` has the value `/usr/bin:/bin`, then your completion function would complete `cle` to `clear` if either `/usr/bin/clear` or `/bin/clear` exists.